# Знаки препинания в сложных конструкциях

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Задание: выпишите цифры, обозначающие запятые между частями сложного предложения, связанными подчинительной связью.

***Я никогда больше пальцем не тронул Оську,*** (1) **как бы он ни задирался,** (2) **а это случалось порой в первые годы нашей так сложно начавшейся дружбы.**

Почему правильный ответ 1, 2? Ведь налицо сочинительная связь под №2.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая 2 выполняет 2 роли: обозначает конец придаточной части в сложноподчинённом предложении и разделяет сложноподчинённое и самостоятельное простое. У Вас задание найти запятые, разделяющие части сложноподчинённого, начало и конец придаточного.

Comment: А если бы под №2 стояла точка с запятой (т.е. бессоюзная связь), как бы мы обозначили конец придаточной части?!?!

Comment: Сложно представить себе(;) перед А. Союз-то остаётся, почему бессоюзное? А если б союза не было, тогда (;) закрывала бы придаточное, тогда бы в ответе было только (1).

Comment: Я и имела ввиду, что союз А отсутствовал бы. Значит пунктуационный знак под №2 выполняет или бессоюзную связь, или сочинительную.

Comment: Я не настаиваю на том, что в Вашем тесте ответ верен у авторов задания(я только пытаюсь объяснить, как они думают) я бы тоже отметила только №1. Просто в ответах КИМов этого года часто имеют в виду начало и конец придаточного, но в данном предложении эта запятая и другую роль играет, получается, некоррекное задание или некорректный ответ.

Comment: А это что, в КИМах было или на экзамене?

Comment: ОГЭ 9 класс. Дочке попался 3 вариант, но это задание не повлияло на оценку. Одна единственная ошибка в тестах только эта. Вот и ломаем голову, как правильно. Считаю, что такие задания не должны быть на экзаменах.

Comment: Спасибо за общение!

Comment: Вы правы, таких не должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Я никогда больше пальцем не тронул Оську, (1) **как бы** он ни задирался, (2) **а** это случалось порой в первые годы нашей так сложно начавшейся дружбы (3).

Предложения 1 и 2 связаны **подчинительной связью** (придаточное уступительное с союзным словом КАК БЫ), **сочинительная связь** (союз а) между сложноподчиненным предложением (1+2)  и предложением 3.

**Но это структура сложного предложения.** Запятая №1 отделяет главную часть от придаточной части,   а вот запятая №2 обозначает сочинительную связь между СПП и самостоятельным предложением 3 и к подчинительной связи не имеет отношения.

**Получается, что ответ такой : запятая №1.** Или другой вариант:  **вопрос поставлен некорректно.**